# .htaccess Redirect 301 - can't load files from mobile directory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mobile

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|ipad|iemobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!m/).*)$ /m/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is how the .htaccess in the my webserver's root looks like.
It redirects successfully to /m but it won't load files from my root directory. I use ../js and ../css in my mobile directory to load such files from it's parent directory. The /m folder doesn't have an .htaccess yet.

Comment: Better to use `/js/` and `/css/`

Comment: "../css/style.css" this is how it looks...

Comment: You can also try adding this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` .

Comment: won't work too. even absolut paths don't work oO

Answer (score 0):

Exclude files and directories from your rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|ipad|iemobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!m/).*)$ /m/$1 [R=302,NE,NC,L]
```

You can also try adding this in the  section of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/" />
```

so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current page's URL.